# How do I add file types to Windows 8 "File Associations"?

Tags: windows-8, file-extension

I am trying to associate .scss files with my text editor, but the file extension is not listed under `Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Set Associations`

How can I set this association if the file extension isn't listed? I see no option to add extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a text file named **example.scss**.

1. Double click it.
2. Make sure "Always use as default program" is checked".
3. Select your text editor

Answer (score 2):

I found this question and answer when searching for a solution in Windows 7.

@surfasb's answer didn't work for me as the checkbox `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file` was greyed out.

@Fred's answer didn't work either, I don't know why but the added file extension didn't show up in `Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > "Associate a file type or protocol with a program"`

Instead I had to do the following:

1. Right-click a file with the file extension you want to set default program for
2. Click `Properties`.
3. In the `General` tab.
4. On the same line as `Opens with:` there is a button `Change...`, press it.
5. Now you get the same pop-up dialog as in @surfasb's answer but with the greyed out `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file` pre-checked.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Control Panel** > **Indexing options** > **Advanced** > **File types** tab.

At the bottom, you should see : *Add new extension to list*

Type the new extension & click add > OK

Fred