# How do I add file types to Windows 8 “File Associations” for Metro apps

Tags: windows-8, file-association, file-types, windows-8-apps

I needed to create a new file type ".pd".  I want to have the Microsoft Reader Metro app open this file type.

Using [How do I add file types to Windows 8 "File Associations"?](https://superuser.com/questions/648618/how-do-i-add-file-types-to-windows-8-file-associations) does not allow me to associate a new file type listed in Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations "Change program..." with an existing Metro app - Microsoft Reader.

Everything I've seen easily associates exe files. (gpedit.msc on the Server, ASSOC, Ftype, etc.)

Basically I want the .PD extension to work exactly like the .PDF extension.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the registry editor. Alternately, use FileTypesMan tool from Nirsoft. Use the option, "Replace File Type For Selected Extension" and set .PD file type association just like .PDF

FileTypesMan - Alternative to 'File Types' manager of Windows : http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html